# What is a floating number and its purpose in terms of theory

Tags: python

I am just learning python and making a calculator and the tutorial says float instead of int. what is a floating number

Why not just use int

Comment: share the code, we can nothing at the moment

Comment: Can't you just google https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+floating+number ... ?

Answer (score 0):

A float is a number with numbers after decimal points, for example 12.56 . It can also be called a real.

An integer is a whole number eg 12.

If you use an integer in a calculator, then you wouldn't be able to calculate with anything other than whole numbers.

for example using int is fine if you do 12 + 12. However, if you enter 12.56 + 12.56, then you will get an error, as the int function assumes that the user enters a whole number

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Floats, contrary to int or integer data types, can store numerical data with much more precision. Integers lose information regarding to the mantissa or decimal portion of the number. So in applications where precision is required, we use float data type instead of int.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question on which you can dive deep, and I would absolutely Google this. For example, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) page on this will already give you a bunch of information.

Now, in order not to overwhelm you with a too much information, we can answer your question without too many details:

A float is a type with which you can represent decimal numbers (numbers with a comma in there, for example 0.5). An int is a type with which you can only represent integers (1, 2, 50, ...).

Don't hesitate to Google around for more info!

Comment: do you know how to consider the qn solved. I am worried people will waste time on such a simple qn

Comment: Next to each answer you can find multiple icons. An up-arrow and a down-arrow: with this you can mark whether a response was helpful or not. But to mark an answer as accepted you have to click the "check mark" icon next to that answer as well :)